# Protractor - "Failed: each key must be a number of string; got undefined"

Tags: protractor

this program is to retrieve the value from other .js file using Protractor.
FirstConnectDatabase.js  - establish the DB connection and Query.
spec.js - retrieve the result from the above .js file.

getting the below Error 
Failed: each key must be a number of string; got undefined

Can anyone help me on this.

```
**spec.js** 
var dbConnect = require('./FirstConnectDatabase.js');
var AptNbr = new dbConnect;

var readAptNbr = AptNbr.Apts;
console.log('Enter the order #'+readAptNbr);  


**FirstConnectDatabase.js**
var retrieveAptNbr = function mySQLDatabase()
{  
    var mysql = require('../../node_modules/mysql');
    var Aptnumber="";
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'local',
    user :'user',
    password :'password',
    database:'DB'
    });   
connection.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log("Error"+err)
  }else{
    console.log('DB is connected');    
  }
});

connection.query("select * from XXXX",function(err,rows) {
 if (!err) 
 {
  console.log("result is :", rows[0].AptNo);

  var Apts = (function() {
    var on = rows[0].Aptnumber;
    return parseInt(on);

  }());

 }else{
  console.log("Error"+err)
 }
});
};
module.exports=retrieveAptNbr;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when we are fetching a string value from other JS file, where string is not present or may be our fetching statement is incorrect. In your case you also fetching value in 'on' variable, check if it is getting some string value or not.

Comment: my fetching value ' ON' variable returns a string value but i am not able to export to other JS. it still shows undefined error. do i am missing some thing ? Any assistance is much appreciated.